# How to delete unused java and xml files from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to do clean up my project which having 1000+ Java classes, but many of them are not in used. Is there easiest way to track unused classes and xmls.

Comment: Right click `find usages`

Comment: [How find all unused classes in Intellij Idea?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22522013)

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze your whole project to find XML, code and all things that are unused or not required with Lint

With this you can find unused classes, resources, security leaks,
refactor suggestions and more, it's really useful.

First right click on your project main package, select Analyze - Inspect Code.

[image]

After that select whole project

[image]

Then you can see all your problems to fix

[image]

An example of an XML error, you can see the errors from the drop down and in the right where they are located, and also you can fix all this problems from the same inspector, above you can see suppress, that is a way to fix this, and you move on to all project problems with this

[image]

Also, you can remove unwanted resources like this, right click in your project structure

[image]

you can select preview and see all the resources which you can delete

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Refactor - Remove unused Resources...
```

[image]